# Complete Riemannian manifolds and lengths of curves diverging to infinity

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I've been working on the following exercise and got stuck:

"Prove that a connected Riemannian manifold is complete if and only if every regular curve that diverges to infinity has infinite length."

Here, a curve with domain $[0,b)$ (and $b$ possibly infinite) diverges to infinity if for every compact subset of the manifold, there exists a time beyond which it does not intersect the compact set anymore.

I was able to prove the forward direction, but I can't figure out how to get the converse. I've tried both to show that maximal geodesics are defined for all time, and when that didn't work, I tried to show Cauchy sequences converge, but I didn't have success in either case. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try again taking geodesic paths defined on finite intervals $[0,T)$. Show that if such a path does not extend continuously to $T$ then it diverges to infinity.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was able to show what you said, and I see that this means that the geodesic path on [0,T) has infinite length. I assume this is supposed to give a contradiction of some sort; perhaps it has to do with the velocity of the geodesic path tending to infinity? I'm not seeing how the problem implication follows.

Comment: Now that you know that your path diverges to infinity, the condition in question states that such a path should have infinite length. What do you think is the length of a geodesic that has speed $a$ and is defined on an interval of length $T$? (Remember, geodesics have constant velocity as they satisfy the equation $c''=0$.)

Comment: One equivalent way to state completeness is: there is an increasing sequence of compact sets $(K_n)$ with each one contained in the interior of the next, their union is the entire manifold, and it has the property that for any sequence $(p_n)$ of points with $p_n\not\in K_n$, then $d(p_n,q)\to +\infty$ for every point $q$. This is a very useful criterion.